# Compare occurrences between str in two lists

Tags: python

I currently learning python and here is my issue:

```
list1 = ["ilovepython","ilovec#"]
list2 = ["love","python"]
```

I wish to use `list2` to check each item in `list1`, the output would be **something** like this:

```
in "ilovepython": 
number of "love" = 1
number of "python" = 1
in "ilovec#"
number of "love" = 1
number of "python" = 0
```

What could be the way to write this code?

Here is my code:

```
list_a = ["ilovepython","ilovec#"]
check = ["love","python"]
result = []

for string in list_a:
    count = 0
    tmp = string
    while check in tmp:
        count += 1
        idx = tmp.find(check)
        tmp = tmp[idx+1:]
    result.append(count)

print(result)
```

But I was confused if I have to check by a list of `str`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, to get your question more well received, you'll need to show what you have coded so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use a nested `for`-loop with formmatted strings:

```
list1 = ["ilovepython","ilovec#"]
list2 = ["love","python"]

for i in list1: # For every string in list11
    print(f'in "{i}":') # Print the string
    for j in list2: # For every string in list2
        num = i.count(j) # Store the number of occurrences of the second string in the first string
        print(f'number of "{j}" = {num}') @ Print the number of ocurrences with a formatted string
```

Output:

```
in "ilovepython":
number of "love" = 1
number of "python" = 1
in "ilovec#":
number of "love" = 1
number of "python" = 0
```

Comment: Hi Ms Ann I just put my code, sorry for the inconvenience
May I ask that from your code,            print(f'in "{i}":')   what is the "f'" means?

Comment: @Martinqq With an `f'` before a string, the regular string turns into a formmated string, meaning you can insert things into the string with `{}`.